# Corebluetooth : Retrieving characteristic.value > 20 bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I currently have a BLE peripheral device that streams 35 bytes of data every 100ms (arduino sketch).  On my iOS device, I've tested using Adafruit's iOS UART program and verified that the iOS device can indeed receive the full 35 bytes of data every 100ms. They use the MQTT libraries.

I am using the CoreBluetooth library and in CBPeripheral's didUpdateValueForCharacteristic: method, the characteristic.value is always 20 bytes or less.  It will usually be 20 bytes -> 100ms -> remaining 15 bytes -> 100ms...repeat.

I'd like to retrieve the entire 35 bytes in one transmission, but on the receiving end it breaks it up into 20 byte chunks whereas the adafruit iOS library using MQTT receives the entire transmission of 35 bytes in 1 shot every 100ms.

Upon further research, I noticed the use of CBPeripheralManager and the didReceiveReadRequest: method but I believe that only belong's on the peripheral BLE device, and not on the host iOS device which I am receiving the data from.

Does anyone have any idea how to retrieve the entire 35 byte transmission?

Comment: It is likely that the adafruit app is simply reassembling the two packets into a single 35 byte message. Under the covers it will be using Core Bluetooth as that is the only way an app can communicate with a BLE peripheral.

Comment: As you are seeing a delay between the 20 bytes and the 15 bytes you should check you settings on the peripheral. It sounds like it has some setting that attempts to fill the buffer before sending but this times out after 100m/s.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11.  On the peripheral, I am sending a 35 byte string and then introduce a 100ms delay.  On the central iOS device, I am picking up 0-19 bytes, then 100ms later the 20-35 bytes.  I tried on the BLE peripheral device to first send the first chunk, second chunk, then introduce the 100ms delay.  However, that still did not work.

Comment: Question, in the didReceiveReadRequest method, do you know whether the passed in parameter characteristic.value's length be > 20 bytes?  I am also thinking that Adafruit's library reassembles on the receiving end, but looking through the code, its difficult to see what is happening.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: There is nothing you do on the central side that controls when notifications of updated data are delivered to your app; they are delivered as soon as they are received. Your problem is definitely on the sending side. I looked at the adafruit code and they don't do anything special. They simply receive the data and pass it to the UartViewController. The most you will get in the notify method is 20 bytes. `didReceiveReadRequest` is for CBPeripheral, not CBCentral

Comment: Yes, sorry I was referring to the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic.  I will look into the sending side to see what is the issue.  On the receiving side in the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic since the most I get notified is 20 bytes, I now have code to reassemble the two packets 20+15.  My assumption is the 15 bytes should come within milliseconds after the 20 byte arrives.

Comment: Check the description of the way data is transmitted in this document - https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-adafruit-bluefruit-le-uart-friend?view=all it is in the section on the ATBLEUARTTX command.